# sqlite3 - Clang / GCC compilation error (macOS) - sample code http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitec/

Tags: sqlite

I tried sample code of http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitec/
gcc gives following error,
can anyone tell me the issue,
also let me know where I can download sqlite3.h for MacOS?

undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
_main in sqlite3_read-bd2f8a.o
"_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
_main in sqlite3_read-bd2f8a.o
"_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
_main in sqlite3_read-bd2f8a.o
"_sqlite3_free", referenced from:
_main in sqlite3_read-bd2f8a.o
"_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
_main in sqlite3_read-bd2f8a.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

You need to link with sqlite3. I think this can be done by passing the path to sqlite3.dylib to clang in addition to the arguments given. You can download sqlite3.h from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html (It's in the "amalgamation" download).